# Trouble with clicking on an image in running IE with SHDocVw

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to simulate a click on a image in IE through C# using SHDocVw but have a problem. My program does not seem to find the img in the code.. Here is what I got:

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows AllBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
    foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in AllBrowsers)
    {
       mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = ieInst.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
       string html = htmlDoc.body.outerHTML;               

           foreach (mshtml.HTMLImg imgElement in htmlDoc.images)
           {
              if (imgElement.nameProp.ToString().Equals("icon_go.GIF"))
              {
                 imgElement.click();
              }
            }
     }
```

Here is a part of the html code im working on:

```
<TD align=center><INPUT title="View Detail Statistics" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 14px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 14px" src="../App_Themes/Company/Images/icon_go.GIF" type=image name=process1></TD></TR>
```

A problem is that the picture IS a button on the website but I dont know how to press it through the C# code.

Is there maybe another way to select the button? Like through the name "process1" instead of going for the image name?

Comment: GIF != gif : set ordinalignorecase in your `.Equals()` test. (and set a breakpoint to make sure it works)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Alex, but even though I changed to .GIF it still skips the click..

Comment: Does it hit .Click in the loop? If so try .InvokeMember("click")

Comment: I see now that it hits the .Click() when I dont have the if-statement: BUT another picture.. I think maybe its because the other image states "IMG" instead of "type=image" in the html code.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in your comment you are looping IMG but you should be looping INPUT:

```
foreach (IHTMLElement element in htmlDoc.all)
{
    var input = element as IHTMLInputImage;
    if (input != null && Path.GetFileName(input.src).Equals("icon_go.GIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((IHTMLElement)input).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this!! Do I need some kond of assembly reference for using IHTML?

Comment: You need the Microsoft.mshtml assembly rather than the COM mshtml reference

Comment: It works!! But now I have to make it wait before the .Click() so the website can completely load.. But thanks Alex, this is great!!

Comment: May as well `break;` after the click as well to avoid checking more elements

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that I want it to go to the next button (there are like 10 buttons with the same name ("icon_go.GIF), so i don't want to break the foreachloop! I just want it to wait until the next page is loaded before the click :)

Comment: Alex, can you maybe take a look at my newest question? You seem to know lots about this stuff. Would be grateful!